# Directive handling event from model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a CurrentUser model class that, when the user is not authenticated, I want to throw a 'NOT_AUTHENTICATED' event.

On certain pages, I want to use a directive that will handle this event and display a modal.

Will emiting events from a model get bubble up to the directive link scope?

Comment: Please use a service injected in your directive and user class instead of scope events when implementing an application signal that has no relation with scopes.

Comment: how can a service listen for an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular events are triggered by and received by scopes. So, you need a $scope object to broadcast an event and you need a scope object to listen to an event. If by "model" you mean an angular service, then you can inject the $rootScope and $broadcast the event from there like this...

```
myApp.factory('theModel', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('NOT_AUTHENTICATED');
});
```

The event will bubble down the scope chain and can be heard by your directive's scope in a link function..

```
myApp.directive('theDirective', function () {
    return {
        ...
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('NOT_AUTHENTICATED', function (event) {
               ...
            }

        }

    };
});
```